# Custom jquery to target second step of form sequence

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a jquery script targeting the "submit" button in the second part of a 2-part  connected form. On a stand-alone version of this same form step (meaning it's not a connected form sequence yet) the script works to disable the submit button until one of two sets of radio buttons has a 'yes'. As part of a sequence, I've hooked in to the event 'cf-connected'. The console.log message fires but none of the rest of the script does.

Functionality I want is, both radio sets can be 'yes', but only one yes is required to submit and remove 'disabled' from the input and also remove the red CSS styles. When this second part of the form is first rendered, I want the submit button disabled with the red CSS styles active. What is happening is nothing of the script runs except for the console.log at the bottom. Here is the code I'm loading on this page:

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'cf.connected', function () {

// grab the two 'Yes' radio buttons
var yesOne = $("#fld_3055776_1_opt1287614");
var yesTwo = $("#fld_3324990_1_opt2062320");

// disable the submit button initially
var submitButton = $("input[value=submit]").prop("disabled", true);

// class allows the change of cursor:not-allowed
submitButton.addClass("disablePointer");

// give the ::after element "disabled" opacity
var divContainer = $(".caldera-grid .form-group.form-submit div").css("opacity", "0.45");

// grab div with red border
var redDiv = $(".submit-filter > div").addClass("red-border");

// add click listener to radio buttons
$("input[type=radio]").on("click", countUp);


function countUp() {
    console.log("countUp is firing");

    if (yesOne.prop("checked")) {
        submitButton.prop("disabled", false).removeClass("disablePointer");
        divContainer.css("opacity", "1");
        redDiv.removeClass("red-border");
    }
    else if (yesTwo.prop("checked")) {
        submitButton.prop("disabled", false).removeClass("disablePointer");
        divContainer.css("opacity", "1");
        redDiv.removeClass("red-border");
    }
    else if ( (yesOne.prop("checked")) && ( yesTwo.prop("checked")) ) {
        submitButton.prop("disabled", false).removeClass("disablePointer");
        divContainer.css("opacity", "1");
        redDiv.removeClass("red-border");
    }
    else {
        submitButton.prop("disabled", true).addClass("disablePointer");
        divContainer.css("opacity", "0.45");
        redDiv.addClass("red-border");
    }
}    


console.log("Form has moved to next part");
```

});

How can I get this script to execute correctly after the DOM of the second step in the form is rendered?

Here is a link to the [staging form with 2 parts](https://seiu2015.staging.wpengine.com/full-seiu-2015-member/) (note the 'steps' at the top of each part of the form do not correlate for the same form step 1 and step 2).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it. I needed to add an event listener to the document on scroll, then run all the above code. Then in order to prevent it from running on every scroll, I put .off() afterwards. The entire code that is now doing what I need it to is:

$(document).on('cf.connected', function() {
    $(document).on('scroll', function() {

```
    // grab the two 'Yes' radio buttons
    var yesOne = $("#fld_3055776_1_opt1287614");
    var yesTwo = $("#fld_3324990_1_opt2062320");

    // disable the submit button initially
    var submitButton = $("input[value=Submit]").prop("disabled", true);

    // class allows the change of cursor:not-allowed
    submitButton.addClass("disablePointer");

    // give the ::after element "disabled" opacity
    var divContainer = $(".caldera-grid .form-group.form-submit div").css("opacity", "0.45");

    // grab div with red border
    var redDiv = $(".submit-filter > div").addClass("red-border");

    // add click listener to radio buttons
    $("input[type=radio]").on("click", countUp);


    function countUp() {
        if (yesOne.prop("checked")) {
            submitButton.prop("disabled", false).removeClass("disablePointer");
            divContainer.css("opacity", "1");
            redDiv.removeClass("red-border");
        }
        else if (yesTwo.prop("checked")) {
            submitButton.prop("disabled", false).removeClass("disablePointer");
            divContainer.css("opacity", "1");
            redDiv.removeClass("red-border");
        }
        else if ( (yesOne.prop("checked")) && ( yesTwo.prop("checked")) ) {
            submitButton.prop("disabled", false).removeClass("disablePointer");
            divContainer.css("opacity", "1");
            redDiv.removeClass("red-border");
        }
        else {
            submitButton.prop("disabled", true).addClass("disablePointer");
            divContainer.css("opacity", "0.45");
            redDiv.addClass("red-border");
        }
    }
    $(document).off('scroll');
});
```

});